# Slick timestamp calculation

Tags: slick, slick-pg

I am using the pg-slick extension for postgres. I try to do a calculation in the where clause but i don't get it working. It always says:

```
value - is not a member of java.sql.Timestamp
```

Filter clause:

```
 .filter(r => Timestamp.from(Instant.now()) - r.lastActivity < Duration.ofMinutes(30))
```

where lastActivity is:

```
def lastActivity = column[Timestamp]("last_activity")
```

and my postgres driver is:

```
trait MyPostgresDriver extends ExPostgresProfile
  with PgPostGISSupport
  with PgDate2Support
  with PgEnumSupport {

  override val api: API = new API {}

  ///
  trait API extends super.API
    with PostGISImplicits
    with DateTimeImplicits
    with PostGISAssistants {
  }
}
object MyPostgresDriver extends MyPostgresDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
val plainAPI = new API
    with Date2DateTimePlainImplicits {}
```

seems to solve the issue. Also don't forget to add `with DateTimeImplicits` and `with PgDateSupport`